# How to get IP and name of Terraform Google Cloud ressource google_compute_instance_template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm using a `google_compute_instance_template` ressource in Terraform and am wondering, how I can access the public IP address and name of the VM that will be created by the template in Terraform.

My template looks like the following:

```
resource "google_compute_instance_template" "tpl" {
  name_prefix             = "${var.name_prefix}-"
  project                 = var.project_id
  machine_type            = var.machine_type
  labels                  = var.labels
  metadata                = var.metadata
  tags                    = var.tags
  can_ip_forward          = var.can_ip_forward
  metadata_startup_script = var.startup_script
  region                  = var.region
  dynamic "disk" {
    for_each = local.all_disks
    content {
      auto_delete  = lookup(disk.value, "auto_delete", null)
      boot         = lookup(disk.value, "boot", null)
      device_name  = lookup(disk.value, "device_name", null)
      disk_name    = lookup(disk.value, "disk_name", null)
      disk_size_gb = lookup(disk.value, "disk_size_gb", null)
      disk_type    = lookup(disk.value, "disk_type", null)
      interface    = lookup(disk.value, "interface", null)
      mode         = lookup(disk.value, "mode", null)
      source       = lookup(disk.value, "source", null)
      source_image = lookup(disk.value, "source_image", null)
      type         = lookup(disk.value, "type", null)

      dynamic "disk_encryption_key" {
        for_each = lookup(disk.value, "disk_encryption_key", [])
        content {
          kms_key_self_link = lookup(disk_encryption_key.value, "kms_key_self_link", null)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  dynamic "service_account" {
    for_each = [var.service_account]
    content {
      email  = lookup(service_account.value, "email", null)
      scopes = lookup(service_account.value, "scopes", null)
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network            = var.network
    subnetwork         = var.subnetwork
    subnetwork_project = var.subnetwork_project
    dynamic "access_config" {
      for_each = var.access_config
      content {
        nat_ip       = access_config.value.nat_ip
        network_tier = access_config.value.network_tier
      }
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = "true"
  }

  # scheduling must have automatic_restart be false when preemptible is true.
  scheduling {
    preemptible       = var.preemptible
    automatic_restart = ! var.preemptible
  }

  dynamic "shielded_instance_config" {
    for_each = local.shielded_vm_configs
    content {
      enable_secure_boot          = lookup(var.shielded_instance_config, "enable_secure_boot", shielded_instance_config.value)
      enable_vtpm                 = lookup(var.shielded_instance_config, "enable_vtpm", shielded_instance_config.value)
      enable_integrity_monitoring = lookup(var.shielded_instance_config, "enable_integrity_monitoring", shielded_instance_config.value)
    }
  }
}
```

I don't have a `google_compute_instance` ressource in my plan, only a `google_compute_instance_template`.

So my question is, how can I access the VM's public IP adresses and names in Terraform?

I have tried `google_compute_instance_template.tpl.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip` but it's empty.

Best regards,
rforberger

Comment: You can't access them, as the instances don't exist yet.

Comment: @Marcin really? Is there no way to access the IP and name of the instances?

Comment: You haven't created any instance yet as you wrote. You have only template.

Comment: The instance are created via MIG using the template.
```
module "managed_instance_group" {
  source            = "../../../terraform-google-vm/modules/mig"
  region            = var.region
  target_size       = 5
  hostname          = "k8s"
  instance_template = module.instance_template.self_link

  target_pools = [
    module.load_balancer_custom_hc.target_pool
  ]

  named_ports = [{
    name = "https"
    port = 6443
  }]
}
```
But how can I access the IP and name of the instances?

Comment: Or in other words: How can I access the IP addresses and names of the instances created by a Google Managed Instance Group (https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/vm/google/latest/submodules/mig)?

Comment: You will be able to create a MIG in terraform, with the number of instance, the scale rules and so on. But the rest isn't managed by Terraform, but by the MIG, and so, terrafom haven't this information. So, first comment of @Marcin: you can't!

Answer (score 4):

Based on the comments.

The [google_compute_instance_template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance_template) is only template, based on which you can create instances using [compute_instance_group_manager](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance_group_manager) or [google_compute_instance_from_template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance_from_template).

Thus, once you create these instance you will be able to access their IP addresses using the instance or MIG resources. But template in itself, does not provide such information. Once you create your MIG, you can use [instances](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/compute_instance_group#instances) attribute from MIG data source to get the instance. But the number and id of the instances changes with time, as they are fully managed by MIG, not by terraform.

Comment: How can I access the instances attribute from the MIG data source? I only have the google_compute_region_instance_group_manager resource, which has the object instance_group, but this is only an URL to the google_compute_instance_group_manager.
I get the following error accessing it: This value does not have any attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `local-exec` to execute the CLI.

```
resource "null_resource" "instances" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "gcloud compute instance-groups managed list-instances <NAME>"
  }
}
```

Replace `<Name>` with a `var` or string representing the MIG.

Comment: This is though not really Terraform like.

Comment: @RonnyForberger - Terraform does not manage the compute engine instances that managed instance groups create. That "workaround" is the only technique that I can think of. If your requirement is a native Terraform provider feature, then it is not possible.